# Need XSLT example

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have one xml need to create xslt with custom tags need to get some example or any help on xslt would be helpful.
this is the input xml what I am getting need to divide into two sections using xslt

### Input:

```
<XMLJRN>
    <P>
        <E name="Statement_Document">Statement_Document</E>
        <E name="StatementIdentifier">MHS</E>
        <E name="CurrencyCode">USD</E>
        <E name="ClaimCount">2</E>

        <E name="Claim">Claim</E>
        <E name="ClaimNumber">050001741183100</E>
        <E name="AmountPaid">0.00</E>
        <E name="CurrencyCode">USD</E>

        <E name="Claim">Claim</E>
        <E name="ClaimNumber">050001741179800</E>
        <E name="AmountPaid">150.00</E>
        <E name="CurrencyCode">USD</E>
    </P>
</XMLJRN>
```

### Desired output:

```
<Doc1Statement_STG>
    <StatementDocument>Statement_Document</StatementDocument>
    <StatementIdentifier>MHS</StatementIdentifier>
    <ClaimCount>2</ClaimCount>
    <Doc1Claim_STG>
        <ClaimNumber>050001741183100</ClaimNumber>
        <AmountPaid>0.00</AmountPaid>
        <ClaimCurrencyCode>USD</ClaimCurrencyCode>
    </Doc1Claim_STG>
    <Doc1Claim_STG>
        <ClaimNumber>050001741179800</ClaimNumber>
        <AmountPaid>150.00</AmountPaid>
        <ClaimCurrencyCode>USD</ClaimCurrencyCode>
    </Doc1Claim_STG>
</Doc1Statement_STG>
```

### My current XLST:

```
<xsl:template match="XMLJRN/P">
 <xsl:apply-templates/> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="E"> 
 <Doc1Statement_STG>
  <xsl:element name="{@name}"> 
  <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
  </xsl:element> 
 </Doc1Statement_STG>
</xsl:template>
```

I am unable to add  tag for each claim amount, any help

Comment: What XSLT have you tried so far and what specific problems are you having with it?

Comment: I have tried with xsl 1.0 , I am unable to divide into sections with one xml.<xsl:template match="XMLJRN/P">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="E">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
   
  </xsl:template> -- it was coming entire thing in one section, i need to insert docclaim_stg based on the claim count, under that group

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, as the formatting is lost. You can edit your own posts as much as you like (there's an "edit" link under each post), and once you've gained some reputation you'll be able to  suggest edits to other people's posts too.

Comment: Sorry.. This is the first post I am posting, I will change in the post thanks for the information

Comment: There's no magic method to split a list of elements into arbitrary tags. You've got to do it node by node.

Comment: Hi Kilazur, I have tried with node by node also, I came upto Claim Count, then after what needs to be done, here I cannot loop for each claim, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0? @Kilazur What makes you think the element names are arbitrary?

Comment: @Mathias I'm talking about specifics, like `Doc1Statement_STG` and `Doc1Claim_STG`. He wants to arbitrary split his list, with these arbitrary node names.

Comment: @Kilazur As far as I can see, `Doc1Statement_STG` is a group starting with `E[@name = 'Statement_Document']` and `Doc1Claim_STG` is a group starting with `E[@name = 'Claim']`. That makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each claim in your input has exactly the structure shown in your example, you can do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Doc1Statement_STG>
        <xsl:for-each select="XMLJRN/P">
            <StatementDocument>
                <xsl:value-of select="E[@name='Statement_Document']"/>
            </StatementDocument>
            <StatementIdentifier>
                <xsl:value-of select="E[@name='StatementIdentifier']"/>
            </StatementIdentifier>
            <ClaimCount>
                <xsl:value-of select="E[@name='ClaimCount']"/>
            </ClaimCount>
            <xsl:for-each select="E[@name='Claim']">
                <Doc1Claim_STG>
                    <ClaimNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::E[@name='ClaimNumber'][1]"/>
                    </ClaimNumber>
                    <AmountPaid>
                        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::E[@name='AmountPaid'][1]"/>
                    </AmountPaid>
                    <ClaimCurrencyCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::E[@name='CurrencyCode'][1]"/>
                    </ClaimCurrencyCode>
                </Doc1Claim_STG>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Doc1Statement_STG>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Excellent Michael, Thank you so much..you saved my one whole day..previously I was using <xsl:for-each select="E[@name='Claim']">, but unable to fetch the items under that group. now I got with your answer we can select using "following-sibling::.. once again thanks Michael